# Plotting sum of two sinusoids in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I would like to plot sum of two sinusoidal in Python, like on attached screenshot.
Could you please recommend how can i do it in matplotlib?
[image]

Comment: Could you include your code, where applicable, and what you have attempted yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already got two solutions. This one gives you something *very similar* to what you want. I could have made it look **exactly** like your output but I leave the remaining part of it as your exercise. Feel free to ask me if you have any doubts. This solution is based on https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.65, width, 0.25]  # left, bottom, width, height
rect2 = [left, 0.4, width, 0.25]
rect3 = [left, 0.1, width, 0.3]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1) 
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect2, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_axes(rect3, sharex=ax1)

x = np.linspace(0, 6.5*np.pi, 200)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(2*x)

ax1.plot(x, y1, color='b', lw=2)
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='g', lw=2)
ax3.plot(x, y1+y2, color='r', lw=2)

ax3.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])

for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
    ax.hlines(0, 0, 6.5*np.pi, color='black')
    for key in ['right', 'top', 'bottom']:
        ax.spines[key].set_visible(False)

plt.xlim(0, 6.6*np.pi)
ax3.text(2, 0.9, 'Sum signal', fontsize=14)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

fig = figure(1)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax1.plot(t, sin(2*pi*t))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax2.plot(t, sin(4*pi*t))
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax3.plot(t, sin(4*pi*t)+sin(2*pi*t))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Check out this solution

- To plot the sum of two sinusoidal in Python, I have used **Matplotlib** and **NumPy** to generate animated sine waves and exported the output as a *gif file*.
- It is a customizable code where the equations and variables for X-axis and Y-axis can be changed in the `animate()` function.

### Python code

```py
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

    plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')

    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    fig.suptitle('Sine waves')

    ax1.set_xlim(0, 4)
    ax1.set_ylim(-4, 4)

    line1, = ax1.plot([], [], color='r', lw=3)
    line2, = ax2.plot([], [], color='g', lw=3)
    line3, = ax3.plot([], [], color='b', lw=6)
    plt.legend([line1, line2, line3],['sin(x1)', 'sin(x2)', 'sin(x1)+sin(x2)'])


    def init():
        line1.set_data([], [])
        line2.set_data([], [])
        line3.set_data([], [])
        return line1, line2, line3


    def animate(i):
        x1 = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
        y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (1.1*x1 - 0.05 * i))
        line1.set_data(x1, y1)

        x2 = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
        y2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (1.21 * x2 - 0.04 * i))
        line2.set_data(x2, y2)

        x3 = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
        y3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (1.1*x3 - 0.05 * i)) + np.sin(2 * np.pi * (1.21 * x3 - 0.04 * i))
        line3.set_data(x3, y3)
    
        return line1, line2, line3


    anim1 = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                     frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

    anim1.save('sine_wave.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

### Output (gif file)

[image: Plotting Animated sum of two sinusoids in Python]

### Uniqueness

- This Python code is unique because it plots animated sine waves using basic python libraries **NumPy** and **Matplotlib** along with the **pillow** library for image processing that is exporting the animated gif.

Comment: This answer plots the two sine waves along with the resultant wave and exports it into a gif file.

Comment: The code presented above can be customized to any given sine equations.

Comment: So you also change the values in the given equations y1, y2, y3

Answer (score 0):

Or something 'simpler':

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
x2 = np.arange(0,20,0.02)

sin1 = np.sin(x)
sin2 = np.sin(x2)

x2 /= 2

sin3 = sin1+sin2

plt.plot(x,sin3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This also can be achieve with `seaborn`

```
import pandas a pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 6.5*np.pi, 200)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(2*x)
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2))
df['diff']=df['y1']-df['y2']
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='x', value_vars=['y1', 'y2','diff'],var_name='condition', value_name='y')

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="condition",
                  height=1.7, aspect=4,)
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "x",'y', alpha=1)

g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.1)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]